# Place cards with different sizes optimally so there is no space left

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, grid

I have multiple ranked cards for which I calculate a size given their rank.
I want them to be placed optimally like in the picture[image: example picture].
How do i create a Heatmap like that dynamically?

This is the card which is generated for each object that i have

```html
<div class="tp-wrapper">
  <div class="tp-box" (click)="toggleFlip()" [@flipState]="flip">
    <div
      class="tp-box__side tp-box__front"
      [ngStyle]="{ background: topicColorMap[object.topic] }"
    >
      {{ object.topic }}
    </div>
    <div
      class="tp-box__side tp-box__back"
      [ngStyle]="{ background: topicColorMap[object.topic] }"
    >
      {{ object.number }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest using flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a *masonry layout*.

Comment: Thanks, the masonry layout is exactly what i was looking for @AmauryHanser

Answer (score 0):

You could try using css grid with this neat trick
(I found here: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/):

grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(250px, 1fr))

*note: adjust the value: 250px according to your needs. This will determine minimum width of the cards.

I hope this helps!